# Bootstrap 3, responsive helper classes, Asteriks

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What is the meaning of the asterisk in these classes in Bootstrap 3:

```
visible-xs-* , visible-sm-* , visible-md-* , visible-lg-*
```

See here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

I replaced the asterisk with the number of columns (e.g. 5 and 7) - no effect , I also left the asterisk in the HTML element's class, which also didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from the same page, just below:

> As of v3.2.0, the .visible-*-* classes for each breakpoint come in three variations, one for each CSS display property value listed below.
>
> Group of classes  CSS display
>
> `.visible-*-block         display: block;`
>
> `.visible-*-inline        display: inline;`
>
> `.visible-*-inline-block  display: inline-block;`

Because when you're using these utilities, it is just switching between `display: none` and another `display` property, you have to specify that end property, whether it is `block`, `inline-block`, or `inline`

Eg:

```
<div class="visible-xs-block">Visible block-level element on xs screens and up</div>
<div class="visible-sm-inline">Visible inline element on sm screens and up</div>
<div class="visible-lg-inline-block">Visible inline block element on lg screens and up</div>
```

Comment: no worries! I was the same after they changed it, but it makes a lot of sense really, you don't always want `display: block`

Answer (score 0):

it's means block,inline,inline-block. `.visible-xs` means , content will be visible for extra small device and `visible-xs-block` means content will be visible for extra small device and it's display property is block. If you write following code

```
<div class="visible-xs-block">
   //content
</div>
```

Then it css will be

```
    .visible-xs-block{display: block;}
```

Hope you are clear

Comment: Ok . If it is helpful for you then accept my answer @user3135691

Comment: Both of your answers were very helpful to me and put the puzzle together. Unfortunately I can only mark one answer as the right one. Sorry.

Comment: Also, the css would be wrapped in `media(min-width: @screen-xs-width) {}`